# What is the difference between ASM LHI and LGHI?

Tags: c++, assembly

In the *.s file of a compiled cpp code by gcc, there are some LHI and LGHI command. I know they mean load address, very similar to LA, but what is the exact difference between them? Is there any document about this? Thanks!

Comment: You should mention which assembly language you're talking about.

Comment: `LGHI` is probably the 64-bit equivalent to `LHI`.

Comment: What processor?  Assembly languages are usually unique to a given processor.  For example, ARM7 assembly is different than 8051 assembly language.